# Open link in an already open tab without refreshing

Tags: html, vue.js, routes

I have a website written in Vue.js. It has several pages.
I need to be able to open one of these pages via a link with query params like in example:
https://example.com/support?type=review

This works ok and routes to the specified page with parameters. One thing that happens is that if already open, browser will use that tab but refreshing the page before routing.

My question is, how to prevent this behavior and instead open this page without refreshing (just like if I routed within my app).

From my other websites I route to "example.com" in following way:

```
<a href="https://www.example.com/support?type=review" target="support">Review Support </a>
```

My main point is to figure out how to route to the website already opened in a tab without refreshing it in Vue.js (if possible).

I have already tried to catch the route in the vue router beforeEach method, but the refresh always happens even before any code is executed on my website.

Is something like this done in `<a>` element which links to my site, or something needs to be done on my website's side?